# Nested class, Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, inner-classes

I plan to implement a list using C++ with nested class as following:

```
class List{
  private:
    class ListItem{
        public:
            ListItem(int val, ListItem* next): _val(val), _next(next){}
            ListItem(int val): _val(val), _next(0){}
            int _val;
            ListItem* _next;
    };

    ListItem* _head;
  public:
    List():_head(0){}
    void add( int );
    void print();
};

void List::add(int val){
    _head = new ListItem(val, _head);
}

void List::print(){
    ListItem* tmp = _head;
    while( tmp ){
        cout<< tmp->_val<< " ";
        tmp = tmp->_next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "List::add(int)", referenced from:
      _main in ccNeyQRz.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Rebuild your project. You compiled with x32 first and now you're trying to link with x64. If using g++, you can use the -m32 or -m64 switches.

Comment: See here: http://ideone.com/ioQTT7 It does work.. You need to "rebuild" the project. Do NOT just press the run button. Go to the menu in your IDE and press rebuild. Either that or delete all the .o files from your project (every  single one). This will make the compiler automatically rebuild them.